# Bluetooth Low Energy Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

what is the difference between Bluetooth and Bluetooth Low Energy and complete example of Bluetooth Low Energy.I am not getting why exactly Bluetooth Low energy is used

Comment: I suppose there is a specification for BLE ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to Classic Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) is designed to provide significantly lower power consumption. This allows Android apps to communicate with BLE devices that have low power requirements, such as proximity sensors, heart rate monitors, fitness devices, and so on.

read more in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

Comment: was searching for this kind of documentation for some time, you saved the day, thanks

Comment: @Moudiz thanks, can you please post any sample example  related to BLE

Comment: @KumarSaurabh I am glad I did :)

Comment: @PoojaNM this might [help you](http://toastdroid.com/2014/09/22/android-bluetooth-low-energy-tutorial/) or [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-example/)